# Проблема с обменом данным между базами 1C с СУБД Postgresql

Tags: 1с, postgresql

Настроен РИБ - главный узел: клиент-сервер 1с версии 8.2.14.540 на ОС fedora 7 + СУБД Postgresql 8.4. подчиненный узел: база в файловом варианте 1С 8.2.14.540 на Windows XP. Проблема такая: обмен на стороне главного узла проходит долго: пример: архив 300 кбайт. - 1 час. А в подчиненном узле быстро проходит - туда архивы уходит в мегабайты и дольше 10 минут не было. Бухгалтера возмущены... так как в процессе обмена все тормозит. Грешу на неоптимальные настройки Postgresql или на недостаток оператичной памяти на сервере: 3ГБайт. Кто что посоветует?...

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте в конфиге постгресса log_min_duration_statement = 0 и посмотрите в логах, какие запросы и как долго там выполняются.